# How do i make random numbers (with limits) add a sum without using solver?

Tags: excel

I've been having trouble with my logic. I need a set of random numbers to add 100. The constraints applied to the numbers are as follow:

number 1 - between 20 and 80

number 2 - between 10 and 40

number 3 - between 5 and 20

I know it's probably simple, but can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can generate the numbers and make them sum 100 :) know that much.

Comment: Not logically possible 2 of the numbers can be random but the 3rd must be based on the random of the other 2.  Given this I would calculate the number 1 last as it has the least probable chance of causing you not to hit 100.  HOwever if 2 is 10 and 3 is 5 then only the number 85 could be used to reach, so you'd have to regen numbers  2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this then columns E to G will be your random numbers.  Column H is a check to ensure your constraints are still satisfied after scaling.  The benefit of this over the macro solution is the computational efficiency since about 80% of attempts results in the constraints being satisfied as opposed to the macro approach which would only yields a little over 1%.  This scaling logic could, of course, be done in a macro but here it is in worksheet functions.
[image]

Edit: looks like my screen capture is approaching unreadable so here are the formulas from left to right for the first row...

```
=RANDBETWEEN(20,80)
=RANDBETWEEN(10,40)
=RANDBETWEEN(5,20)
=SUM(A1:C1)
=A1/($D1/100)
=B1/($D1/100)
=C1/($D1/100)
=IF(AND(E1>=20,F1<=80,G1>=5,G1<=20),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When do these calculations need to perform? (as it stands using randomBetween recalculates each time cells change value. and there is a chance a number 15-19 could appear for number one.  I'm trying to figure out how to prevent it w/o using a macro...

[image]

Comment: That's how I have it now. Can I then run a while loop to run while number 1 is not between range? Sorry, not excel savvy.

Comment: Like while 1 is not > 20 and not < 80, generate 2 and 3? And the generation only has to happen once (1000 times) then I copy the values and use them as is.

Answer (score 0):

(*If at first you don't succeed...*)

Easy.....just run this small macro:

```
Sub randommm()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    zum = 0
    While zum <> 100
        v1 = wf.RandBetween(20, 80)
        v2 = wf.RandBetween(10, 40)
        v3 = wf.RandBetween(5, 20)
        zum = v1 + v2 + v3
        DoEvents
    Wend
    [A1] = v1
    [A2] = v2
    [A3] = v3
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!

**EDIT#2**:

Remove the old macro and replace it with:

```
Sub randommm()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To 1000
        zum = 0
        While zum <> 100
            v1 = wf.RandBetween(20, 80)
            v2 = wf.RandBetween(10, 40)
            v3 = wf.RandBetween(5, 20)
            zum = v1 + v2 + v3
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Cells(i, 1) = v1
        Cells(i, 2) = v2
        Cells(i, 3) = v3
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will look up how to run macros :) Sorry, but could you nest that loop to make the numbers generate 1000 times, please?

Comment: My **EDIT#1** gives macro instructions..................I don't understand the 1000 loop request??

Comment: I need it to run 1000 times, and I need the values in one place (I have to use them in formulas) Thanks for the edit, just ran my first macro :)

Comment: How about the first three values in **A1, B1, C1**  and the remaining 999 samples below them??

Comment: Do I have to change the values in the macro for every iteration?

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that the while loop will have to run nearly 100 times to get 1 good set of randoms.  Unless OP needs integers it'd be much more efficient to just scale the randoms so that their sum will be 100.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I agree that generating two randoms and calculating the third will save time, but the number of iterations should not be a problem ................on my elderly Dell laptop (Win 7 / Excel 2007) the 1000 sample were generated in under 3 seconds.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I didn't actually suggest calculating the third based on first two but to use `randbetween` for all 3 and then scale them so that their sum is 100.  If this is a 1 off thing for OP then yeah 3 sec is no issue.  If they eventually want 1,000,000 samples then 3sec per 1000 samples is pretty darn slow.